# Passing argument to python which is half "<direct string>" and half value of a variable

Tags: python-2.7, arguments

I want to pass a value to the makedir() function that will be something like this:
os.makedir("/myfolder/dt")
where dt = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d %B, %Y")
and I want to create a folder inside the folder named myfolder with the name as the value of the string dt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can incorporate non-string data into strings with something like:

```
intval = 42
strVal = "The value of intVal is %d" % (intVal)
```

(the parentheses around `intVal` aren't necessary in this case but I tend to prefer them just for consistency).

Hence what you're after is something like:

```
makedir ("/myfolder/%s" % (datetime.date.today().strftime("%d %B, %Y")))
```

Alternatively, since you can give arbitrary text to `strftime`, just use:

```
makedir (datetime.date.today().strftime("/myfolder/%d %B, %Y"))
```

Comment: for l in range(0, 100):
    dt = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d %B, %Y_%r" % l) 
    if not os.path.exists(dt):
        os.mkdir(dt)
        break
please help me with this, I want to create <date>_1 or <date>_2, etc folders if the previous ones exist.